# How to set custom month start date and end date in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

my salary month start in previous month 26th and ends in this month 25
ie February month is 2016-01-26 to 2016-02-25.

i need the out put as below

```
$date = '2014-02-27';  
echo date('F', strtotime($date)); = "March" //if date > 25 print next month
```

Comment: So you want to print end date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you have to do is get the day:

```
$date = '2014-02-27';  
$day = date('d', strtotime($date));
```

Then see if bigger than 26, increase one month

```
$month = date('F', strtotime($date));

if($day > 26)
{
$ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n", strtotime($date)) + 1, 1);
$tmpNewDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $ts);
$month = date('F', strtotime($date));

}

echo $month;
```

Comment: hi @peter i think this must be $month = date('F', strtotime($date));
$month = date('F', strtotime($tmpNewDate));

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, I have prepared several date inputs :

```
<?php
    $input_date = '2014-2-2';
    // $input_date = '2014-2-27';
    // $input_date = '2014-12-27';
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $input_date);
    $next_month = null;
    $year = $date->format('Y');
    $next_month = $date->format('m');
    if ($date->format('d') >= 26)
        $next_month = intval($date->format('m')) + 1;       
    if ($next_month == 13){
        $next_month = 1;
        $year = intval($year) + 1;
    }
    echo "next month = " . $next_month . ", year = " . $year;
?>
```